# Is there a way to change the interpolation when upscaling a lower resolution on Windows with an Nvidia GPU?

Tags: windows, graphics-card, resolution, nvidia-graphics-card, scaling

Let's say I put my desktop (1920x1080 native) resolution to something custom like 480x270, which is exactly 4 times smaller than my 1080p native resolution, which SHOULD look really sharp with nearest filtering, but either my GPU or my display forces a linear filtering which looks completely blurry even though every pixel should fit into exactly 4x4 pixel on my screen?

Here's an example of what I mean :

Upscaling with nearest filtering

[image: Nearest filtering]

Upscaling with linear filtering

[image: Linear filtering]

Is there a way (directly with my hardware, with 3rd party software or with my nvidia drivers) to force this kind of nearest filtering?

Comment: What graphics card do you have?

Comment: GeForce GTX 980